# SSRS email data-driven subscription, value is not valid for setting 'Include Link'

Tags: reporting-services

I am using SSRS data-driven subscription by email. 
undering Delivery Type, Include Link
I use Select a value from the database which is a string `www.google.ca`

errors;
Error occurred processing subscription: The value 'www.google.com' is not valid for setting 'Include Link'.
i tried `https://www.google.ca` , error happened again.

What is the correct format (data type) for Include Link?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have misunderstood the purpose of the "Include Link" option for Email Delivery. This option can have only two values; True or False.

If True, then a hyperlink *to the report* is automatically included in the email body.

I suggest you take a look at this [E-Mail Delivery in Reporting Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160334.aspx) article on TechNet.